# Formatting JSON print out for a collapsible-set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery Mobile to print out a set of data obtained from a server via Ajax. I am currently able to obtain it but it doesn't fit when I try to input the information into a collapsible-set format.

I want the layout to be as follows where the information is stored inside the drop down menu and appears when I click it.

[image: Benefit1]

But currently the the information appears outside of the drop down menu as follows:

[image: Benefit2]

Is there a way I can rectify this issue. I tried moving the id value around to the different div tags but it is not helping. My code as follows. Thanks for guide.

HTML

```
<article data-role="content" >
    <div data-role="collapsible-set" >
        <div data-role="collapsible" id="benefitsList">
            <!--hard coded just for reference. I will be removing these h1,p tags-->
            <h1 >Benefit 1</h1>
            <p>Next Payout</p>
            <p>Date: 27 Mar</p>
            <p>Days: 0</p>
            <p>Amount: 47.00</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Javascript

```
$.getJSON("http://www.mocky.io/v2/533604e8f5aa39b117bc2d26",function(data)
{
    //Loop for each element on the data
    $.each(data,function(elem)
    {
        //Create the h1 and the other elements appending them to benefits List
        $("<h1/>",
        {
            text:data[elem].reference
        }).appendTo("#benefitsList")

        $("<p/>",
        {
            text:"Date: "+ data[elem].due.date
        }).appendTo("#benefitsList")

        $("<p/>",
        {
            text:"Days: "+ data[elem].due.days
        }).appendTo("#benefitsList")

        $("<p/>",
        {
            text:"Amount: "+ data[elem].amount
        }).appendTo("#benefitsList")
    })
})
```

Edited:

Duplicate entry

[image: Duplicate Entry]

Comment: You're missing a closing </div> tag.

Comment: I have edited the codes. I missed that tag when copying over. It is not causing the bad format.

Comment: I've made an Angular directive for this 
http://mohsenweb.com/json-formatter/dist/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a slight change in the id placement

```
<article data-role="content">
    <div data-role="collapsible-set" id="benefitsList">
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <!--hard coded just for reference. I will be removing these h1,p tags-->
             <h1>Benefit 1</h1>

            <p>Next Payout</p>
            <p>Date: 27 Mar</p>
            <p>Days: 0</p>
            <p>Amount: 47.00</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

and some other tweaks in javascript

```
$.getJSON("http://www.mocky.io/v2/533604e8f5aa39b117bc2d26", function (data) {
    //Loop for each element on the data
    $.each(data, function (elem) {
        // create wrapper div
        var wrap = $("<div/>").attr('data-role', 'collapsible');
        //Create the h1 and the other elements appending them to benefits List
        $("<h1/>", {
            text: data[elem].reference
        }).appendTo(wrap);

        $("<p/>", {
            text: "Date: " + data[elem].due.date
        }).appendTo(wrap);

        $("<p/>", {
            text: "Days: " + data[elem].due.days
        }).appendTo(wrap);

        $("<p/>", {
            text: "Amount: " + data[elem].amount
        }).appendTo(wrap);
        wrap.appendTo('#benefitsList');
    });
    // finally refresh the list to recreate
    $( "#benefitsList" ).collapsibleset( "refresh" );
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZjUgY/)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Your code works. But every time I go to benefits page, it starts with a duplicate entry. As in At first I get 6 benefit entries(1,2,3,1,2,3) instead of 3. When I hit refresh button, it shows correctly as in it shows 3 benefits. I am following your exact code. Any idea why? Added an image of the duplicate entry for reference. Thanks.

Comment: Found the problem. It causes duplicates when I run the command inside $(document).on("pagecreate",function(). I wanted to use pagecreate to keep the information on the page updated each time the page loads. Guess I got to find another way.